# Mongo DB update keeping uncommon fields in NiFi

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, apache-nifi

Hi I have the following document:

```
{
    "meta" : {
        "country" : "IT",
        "period" : 24.0,
        "region" : "europa",
        "clusters" : [ 
            {
                "1" : "Aged 35 to 49"
            }, 
            {
                "2" : "Male"
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta_id" : "SOCIO"
}
```

and this one:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d42ada8d223f9e56f3f1394"),
    "meta" : {
        "country" : "IT",
        "period" : 24.0,
        "region" : "europa",
        "start_process" : 1555290425.0,
        "from" : 1555200003.0,
        "end_date" : null,
        "start_date" : null,
        "clusters" : [ 
            {
                "1" : "Aged 35 to 49"
            }, 
            {
                "5" : "Aged 0"
            },
            {
                "2" : "Female"
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta_id" : "SOCIO"
}
```

What I want to do is update the common fields of the first doc with the fields of the second and keep/add the uncommon fields (whether they come from the first or the second).
How can I do it with mongodb syntax or is there any processor property I need to set?
Here the processor:
[image]

Comment: can you provide more details? Are the documents in same/different collection(s)? How to define which one must be updated with values of other? Can there be more than 2 docs to merge?

Comment: I am running "Mongo Put" processor on Apache NIFI I should somehow explicit an update query

Comment: i expect( but not sure) that your processor is doing something like 'for each property of second doc, $set {property name: property value} in first doc.  there's probably a dynamic query constructor in your processor